# a4j:commandButton only make ajax call once

Tags: ajax, jsf

```
<h:panelGroup id="someform" layout="block">
        <h:inputText id="inputId"
                     required="true"
                     requiredMessage="Please provide a valid input"/>
            <rich:messages/>
        <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                           execute="someForm"
                           render="someForm"
                           action="#{myController.myMethod}"
                           data="#{myBean.input}"/>

</h:panelGroup>
```

I want to use commandButton to pass input data to myBean.input. If I enter nothing and click on the button, an error message displayed. Then I enter some content and click on the button, the ajax call is not fired. It is not passing anything. If I reload the page then enter some content and click the button, the ajax call is fired.

Somehow,the a4j:commandButton works only for the first time you click on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `a4j:commandButton` without `data`. It is possible that problem with saving data affect functionality of commandButton action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render inputId instead of complete form.

```
<h:panelGroup id="someform" layout="block">
   <h:inputText id="inputId"
                required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please provide a valid input"/>
   <rich:messages id="errorMessages" />
   <a4j:commandButton value="Submit"
                      execute="@form"
                      render="inputId errorMessages"
                      action="#{myController.myMethod}"
                      data="#{myBean.input}"/>

</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. So render text and messages instead of surrounding container.

Comment: But why should that make a difference? Rendering a the 'form' or not has been an 'issue' but rendering a container or individual items should not make a difference